# Python TypeError with for logic iterating data values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, typeerror

I'm having a problem getting the `for` loop of the `json.load()` function to read through the "alarmst" fields and bring back their values.

I have working code above the problem code that works fine with the same data getting the "tag" field data values just fine.

I think it may be related to the `dataStatus` and `dataStart` having time formatted data with semicolons i.e. (`2015-12-10T05:59:03Z`) so I'm not sure how to parse those out or replace characters in the values in the loop before running through the `writerow()` function, or if someone knows of a better way to tell it that the data type of the value of those specific fields is `Date` or something explicit like that with Python.

### Working Code without additional "alarmst" loop and Date formatted data

```
import json
import csv

with open('C:\\folder\\dev\\Tags.txt',"r") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

with open('C:\\folder\\dev\\Tags.csv',"w",newline='') as file:

    csv_file = csv.writer(file)
    for dev in data["devs"]:
        for tag in dev["tags"]:
            csv_file.writerow([tag['id'], tag['name'], tag['dataType'], tag['description'], tag['alarm'], tag['value'], tag['quality'], tag['DevTagId']])
```

### Trouble Code with the error

```
import json
import csv

with open('C:\\folder\\dev\\TagAlarms.txt',"r") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

with open('C:\\folder\\dev\\TagAlarms.csv',"w",newline='') as file:
    csv_file = csv.writer(file)
    for dev in data["devs"]:
        for tag in dev["tags"]:
            for alarm in tag["alarmst"]:
                csv_file.writerow(alarm['dateStatus'],[alarm['dateStart'], alarm['status'], alarm['type']])
```

### The Error

```
    csv_file.writerow(alarm['dateStatus'], [alarm['dateStart'], alarm['status'], alarm['type']])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

### Sample Data

```
{
  "success": true,
  "moreDataAvailable": true,
  "devs": [
    {
      "id": 111111,
      "name": "dev123",
      "tags": [         
        {
          "id": 10100,
          "name": "CleanTask",
          "dataType": "Bool",
          "description": "",
          "alarmHint": "",
          "value": 0,
          "quality": "good",
          "alarmst": {
            "dateStatus": "2016-11-08T06:58:06Z",
            "dateStart": "2016-11-08T06:22:16Z",
            "status": "RTN",
            "type": "None"
          },
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your json data? The error is telling you that `alarm` is a string, not a dict.

Comment: Your data is not a valid JSON file.

Comment: @kindall I agree... it is only a sample of the valid JSON data that's related to the part of the question I was having trouble with. Luckily, this sample seemed to paint the picture for the answer that worked to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is the line:

```
for alarm in tag["alarmst"]:
    csv_file.writerow(alarm['dateStatus'],alarm['dateStart'], ...)
```

Notice that in your data, the value for `alarmst` is a JSON object, which in python is translated into a dictionary. So when you iterate over it, you end up with the keys: i.e. `alarm` will be `"dateStatus", "dateStart", "status", ...`.

Replace it with:

```
alarm = tag["alarmst"]
csv_file.writerow(...)
```

Comment: @ITSolutions So pass it a list, eg `csv_file.writerow([alarm['dateStatus'], alarm['dateStart'], alarm['status'], alarm['type']])`

Comment: @ITSolutions The code in my comment passes a _single_ arg to `csv_file.writerow`: the list `[alarm['dateStatus'], alarm['dateStart'], alarm['status'], alarm['type']]`. Your code passes _two_ args: the string `alarm['dateStatus']` and the list `[alarm['dateStart'], alarm['status'], alarm['type']]`.