# Python CSV export 4000 line limit

Tags: python, json, csv

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40535615/python-typeerror-with-for-logic-iterating-data-values) I posted a while back I'm parsing through JSON formatted data and extracting it to CSV files in the format as needed.

I'm noticing now that working with larger JSON extracts that the CSV file which the data goes to just stops creating records after line 4000, <strike>**but the JSON raw data file certainly has many more rows it should extract than 4000**</strike>. . .  so that's what I thought and was wrong about. I ended up adding an answer to this question below for what applied in my case, the vendor suggested fix, and my actual applied fix that resolved the problem.

### Related Questions

- Is there a 4000 line export limit or line read limit using the Python methods listed below?
- > ```
  > with open(RawDataFile,"r") as file:
  >     data = json.load(file)
  >
  > with open(CsvFile,"w",newline='') as file:
  >     csv_file = csv.writer(file)
  > ```
- Is there any way to workaround issue where all rows can be exported to the file regardless of the number of records/rows?

  - I'd even consider logic that would put each set of 4000 records into it's own file is the last part of the file name could be iterated automatically with a count number e.g. `<filename1>`, `<filename2>`, `<filename2>`,and so on with each having no more than 4000 records.
- Ideally I'd like to stay with Python even if using a different method than this to get all the data into one file as CSV parsed accordingly.

---

### Full Python Logic (changed a little though)

*I need to be able to export all records to a flat file and not just the first 4000. The format using the below gets me exactly what's needed format wise.*

```
import json
import csv
import sys

RawDataFile = sys.argv[1]
CsvFile = sys.argv[2]

with open(RawDataFile,"r") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

with open(CsvFile,"w",newline='') as file:
    csv_file = csv.writer(file)

    for dev in data["devs"]:
        for tag in dev["tags"]:
            if "history" in tag:
                for hist in tag["history"]:
                    csv_file.writerow([tag['TagId'], hist['date'].replace('T',' ').replace('Z',''), hist['value']])
```

---

### Environment Specs

- Windows Server 2008 Enterprise x64 (unfortunately)

  - 144 GB of RAM
  - [image]
- Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: read your csv files in chunks and append the content to destination file

Comment: There is no limit, barring memory constraints. I regularly work with flat files in the hundreds of thousands or even tens of millions of rows.

Comment: Is your Python a 64 bit version? What sort of memory are you working with?

Comment: I don't see anything obvious in your code. Are you sure that's not just the extent of your data? Have you tried somehow counting?

Comment: @wu4m4n I'm confused, the OP never mentioned xlsx. The standard `csv` library should be sufficient and memory efficient.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes! the csv is more efficient without a doubt !, I only comment on what has already worked for me.  If this data will not go to mongodb or somewhere else (nosql dbs), maybe this data will be open in office or in openoffice so my recommendation could help in that scenario. (sorry my english)

Comment: I'm really sure that the number of lines in a csv is only limited by the disk size when you write it line by line like in shown code. I would be less sure of the limits of an in-memory json object. Did you try to simply *count* the total number of `dev`, `tag` and `hist` that your json object contains? And how was your *big* json file generated? Did you control that is was not composed of several smaller json?

Comment: Can you put a counter next to csv_file.writerow() to ensure that you are calling this method more than 4000 times. And similarly in the "devs", "tags" and "history" loops to ensure you are reading out all of the data file. Basically it would be worth knowing if the read is limiting you, or the write. Do you have some data where you would know the expected counts? I have a feeling whatever is giving you these data files is chunking and has implemented the 4000 row max.

Comment: @Walmart It's fine, as long as your problem is dealt with you can answer it yourself. I don't think it's necessary to delete. The question itself, I think, was well written, even if the underlying issue was something a bit underwhelming, it can serve as part of the repository of knowledge SO strives to be. I deal with these sorts of things myself on a day-to-day basis, and I get a lot of value from just being exposed to other people's issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There is no Python CSV export 4000 line limit**

My issue was just as @juanpa.arrivillaga suggested; the data files I got were cutoff just at the 4000 record level so Python was parsing the JSON data to CSV just fine based on what data it had.

I confirmed with vendor support that the device we call the JSON file from via a URL API call with parameters, etc. cuts off at 4000 records for some reason.

Therefore, I made a bad and unverified assumption that I had all the data from the date and time frame parameters passed in the URL call to the device as the support documents mentioned the limitation. In fact, I was told there was not a limitation with this method until I sent them the URLs to support for them to try and then they confirmed themselves exactly what I saw.

**Suggested Fix**

The suggested fix in my case was to call a different URL but that URL did a sync and didn't allow calling data based on date and time stamps.

**Applied Fix**

I build some logic to make a call for a 24 hour time period for any given date based on each one hour period per day it's run from `00:00:00 - 00:59:59`, `01:00:00 - 01:59:59`, all the way through `23:00:00 - 23:59:59` iterating accordingly in one hour increments. It seems that data within a one hour time frame never exceeds the 4000 record limit so in my case this sort of solution is a workaround to the records limitation of the device /server services that gives the called records.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure because I don't know what your data is like, but there is a limit on field size for csv that you can change. In python 2.7 the default is:

```
import csv
print csv.field_size_limit()
```

output: 131072

This seems to be the maximum for python 2.7. Maybe by using `newline = ''` you are inadvertently concatenating lines and thusly creating a large field.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but it wasn't the `newline = ' '` nor a field truncate, etc. type issue either... It was the actual data was cutoff at 4000 records; Python doesn't seem to have this limit as I assumed.